# Sencha ExtJS Json Transformation

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

So, I am making a login form.

Sencha is expecting any Json response to typically have the following format:

```
{  
  "root" : {
    "success": true/false,
    "message": ...,
    "id": ...,
    "metaData": ...,
  }
}
```

However, the actualy Json Response I got looks like this:

```
{
  "SessionId":"1", //doesn't exist if login error
  "UserName":"admin", //doesn't exist if login error
  "ResponseStatus":{
    //blank or failed to login error list 
  }
}
```

The format is from 3rd party, so I can't change it. It is not straight forward to map these fileds because of different structures.

My gut feeling is telling me that I should write the custom json data transformation in Ext.Form -> Reader/errorReader -> Functions. However, I am new to ExtJS and I don't have the brain juice to  glue it together. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom reader as per Johan.

If your json doesn't have a root, then don't tell your reader to use a root...

```
Ext.define('My.model.Model1', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:[
    'SessionId',
    'UserName'
    ],
    proxy:{
      type:'ajax',
      url:'./app/data/response.json',
      reader:{
        type:'json',
        messageProperty:'ResponseStatus'
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Getting close, but you see, I am using a Ext.Form.Panel and the reader in the form. So there is no Model or Proxy? How do I fit that in?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, you'll nead to create your own Reader. Something like this answer in this post:

[how to configure extjs reader to read this json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969437/how-to-configure-extjs-reader-to-read-this-json)

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.reader.JsonPWithoutRoot', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    read: function(response) {
        return this.callParent([ { root: response } ]);
    },
    root: 'root'
});
```

your store proxy config:

```
proxy: {
    type    : 'json',
    reader  : {
        type: 'json',
        root: ''
    }       
}
```